# How to inject custom service to angular component in plain ES5 (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-5, angular2-services

I have a working angular2 `Componen`t.
I implemented a class for some service (using `ng.core.Class` if that matters).
What are the minimal steps to inject my service to my `Component`? Should I include my service in bootstrap function? Should I use any of `ng.core.Inject` or `ng.core.Injectable?` All my experiments failed so far.

Comment: I refer to current beta version of angular2 in this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it super simple. Just create a class an pass it through `providers` property or through `bootstrap`

For example

```
 // Alternative 1
 var Service = ng.core.Class({
  constructor : function() {},
  someFunction : function() {
    console.log('Some function');
  }
})

// Alternative 2
var Service = function() {}
Service.prototype.someFunction = function() {
  console.log('Some function');
}
```

Then pass it to the component

```
var Component = ng.core.
      Component({
        selector: 'cmp',
        template : '',
        providers : [Service]
      }).
      Class({
        constructor: [Service, function(svc) {
          svc.someFunction();
        }]
      });
```

Or through bootstrap

```
ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(Component, [Service]);
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/BEVGbumpMgeX1flBE9Db?p=preview) so you can take a look at it.

**Reference**

- [Class](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/util/decorators.ts#L208) (you can find some examples of its usage in the comments)

Comment: Thanks. It works that way. The reason it *not* worked for me is that I was trying to refer to `Service` before I created it. So the order of js files loading is important with such approach.

Comment: @SergeyP.akaazure can you please accept the answer if it answers your question?

Comment: what if i need to use two services?? how can i specify that in constructor?