# Angular 2: Inject view/DOM into component constructor

Tags: angularjs, angular

I can't figure out how to give a component a reference to its view, to do things like focus on input elements when the form is shown. I can't appear to inject `Element` or `ng.core.ViewRef` or `ng.core.View` into the constructor. How can I get access to the view?

In Angular 1, I would do this with $link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably `ElementRef` and its `nativeElement` field, but you should avoid accessing the DOM this way.
I think a better way is to add a template variable like `<input #inp>` and the access it with `@ViewChild('inp') input`. In `ngAfterViewInit` `input` references the input element.

See also [angular 2 / typescript : get hold of an element in the template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681)

Comment: That sounds about right. I'm struggling to find an example of that in ES5, though--know of an example or resource out there?

Comment: I don't know the details because I use only Dart, but this should show how to use DI in ES5 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532138/how-to-inject-custom-service-to-angular-component-in-plain-es5-javascript

Comment: Oh, sorry, I can get an ElementRef, and thanks for the pointer there! I was actually looking for how to do `@ViewChild` in ES5 and couldn't turn anything up.

Comment: I found only `ng.core.ViewChild(myPredicate, 'myChildComponent', myComponent);` in https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html

Answer (score 6):

I would also caution against direct DOM access in Angular, but here is an example of how to do it:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'jquery-integration',
    templateUrl: './components/jquery-integration/jquery-integration.html'
})
export class JqueryIntegration implements OnInit {

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.moving-box').draggable({containment:'#draggable-parent'});
    }
}
```

The key idea is to inject elementRef. You can then treat that as a regular DOM element. In my example here I am using jquery, but you can use standard DOM access as well.

More info: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0

Answer (score 1):

Just to expound on @Gunter's response above, you would use @ViewChild like this:

```
@ViewChild('myElem') myInput : ElementRef;
inputVal:string;

doSomething( input ){

  let startCursor = this.myInput.nativeElement.selectionStart;
  this.myInput.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(startCursor-1, startCursor-1);
}
```

html looks like this:

```
 <input #myElem type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputVal" maxlength="5" (keyup)="doSomething( myElem )"
```