# JS service in TS Angular2+ application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need some of the GAPIs, but unfortunately, the best definitions I found are still not complete, and I don't have the time right now to make a tool to regenerate the .d.ts from the discovery files (if someone can suggest a quick way, I am happy to try it). Anyway, my "service" is ready in JavaScript (based on: [How to inject custom service to angular component in plain ES5 (Javascript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532138/how-to-inject-custom-service-to-angular-component-in-plain-es5-javascript)), and I am trying to use it in the project:

```
"use strict"; 
var ConfigurationService = ng.core.Injectable().Class({
  constructor: function() {},
  // Other methods here ...
});

export default ConfigurationService;
```

I have even created a .d.ts for it, but I still can't import:
[image]
Of course `"allowJs": true` is there.

Then I have removed the braces, and import was accepted (as long as there is a .d.ts file):
[image]

But build fails anyway:
[image]
I suppose I am totally wrong here...

**Could someone please post a skeleton of an Angular2+ service written in JS, but consumed in TS?** Thank you!

Comment: why dont you try and import the package like a third party lib into angular  eg - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35796961/angular-2-adding-3rd-party-libs

Comment: How will that make my code act as Service in Angular? 
1) `gapi`, `gapi.client` and `gapi.auth2` are allready installed. I need them. It would help me if I could "extend" `gapi.client` somehow with a `gapi.client.drives:any` and `gapi.client.drives.files:any`

Comment: you can then use these js files in service and then inject them to your component that might help roight?

Comment: Yepp... this was ultimately the workaround. Still does not work as expected, but at least it gets compiled :)
Anyway, it would be interesting to see such a skeleton... after all TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript